# how to check the password in django1.6?

Tags: python, django

please help fix the error

I check the user's password in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from userprofile.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm

class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password_old = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def clean_password_old(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password_old = cleaned_data.get("password_old") 
        if not User.check_password(password_old):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords is not correct")
        else:
            return cleaned_data

    def clean(self):    
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 != password2:      
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must be same")
        else:                           
            return cleaned_data
```

but after submitting the form on the screen get the following error message:

```
TypeError at /userprofile/password_page/
check_password() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw_password'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile/password_page/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
check_password() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw_password'
```

Answer (score 2):

This line doesn't really make sense:

```
if not User.check_password(password_old):
```

You're calling `check_password` on the User class, rather than on an instance. But you need to check the password of an actual user, which means you have to actually have that user.

In any case, there's no point writing this yourself. Django already includes a change_password view complete with form: see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change).

Comment: the problem is that I do not know how to transfer from request.user views.py in forms.py